# Autofac MVC4 using IIndex<,> in CI throws EntryPointNotFoundException when try to resolve via indexer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I have setup next thing:

A marker interface, IFormatter, a generic interface ITypedFormatter, a base class FormatterBase and a bunch of implementations upon that FormatterBase.

Looks something like this:

```
public interface IFormatter{}
public interface ITypedFormatter<T> : IFormatter {...}
public abstract class FormatterBase<T> : ITypedFormatter<T> {...}

public class SomeFormatter<SomeClass> : FormatterBase<SomeClass> { ... }
```

I register them with autofac as:

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeFormatter>().Keyed<IFormatter>(typeof(SomeClass));
```

Then I use it in another class to collect them via an IIndex and use it in a method:

```
public class SomeService
{
    public SomeService(IIndex<Type, IFormatter> formatterFactory){...}

    public T Format<T>(T entity)
    {
        var formatter = formatterFactory[typeof (T)];
        var typedFormatter = formatter as ITypedFormatter<T>;
        if(typedFormatter == null)
            return default(T);

        return typedFormatter.Format(entity);
    }
}
```

All the wiring via controller and so on works fine. I can see all the registrations and all. But from the moment I get to first line of the method I get the EntryPointNotFoundException.

The weirdest is, when setting a breakpoint on the first line of the method and set the formatter field via the watch window of visual studio and skip the step all works fine.

When I try to resolve outside of this method, right after setting the DependencyResolver it also works:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
var iindex = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IIndex<Type, IFormatter>>();
var test = (ITypedFormatter<SomeClass>) iindex[typeof (SomeClass)];
```

The only difference I see between the above and the application running is that the service is called from within the internal execution path of the **System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model)** method. I also tried with the **NewtonSoft.Json.JsonSerializer** but no luck.

I'm really puzzled with this one.

Comment: What do you mean on `in CI throws...`? What is the assembly structure of your type? So which type lives in which assembly are the assembly references are correctly set up? Do you load assemblies dynamically?

Comment: All registrations happen in the mvc application via Module, all interfaces/classes are in a domainmodel assembly. CI: constructor injection. I think the problem isn't in the resolving itself since I am able to resolve during runtime (see last peace of code). It is just that one particular case _var formatter = formatterFactory[typeof (T)];_ that causes the problem in the service class.